# complex curve integral definition

Tags: complex-analysis

In my course, this is the given definition of a complex curve integral :

> Consider $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow U$ a piecewise $C^1$-curve, where $U\subset C$ is an open set and $f: U \rightarrow C$ be holomorphic. The complex curve integral of $f$ along $\gamma$ is defined as : 
>   $$\int_{\gamma}fdz=\int_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$$

In the exercice sheet, I have to compute :
$$\int_{\gamma}\overline{z}dz$$ 
over a given closed curve. But, we can show that $z \mapsto \overline{z}$ is nowhere holomorphic which contradicts the definition because $f$ needs to be holomorphic to be integrated ?

Comment: Actually, that's how we define the integral along a curve for any *continuous* function $f$.

Comment: Why would you need $f$ to be holomorphic? Continuity should be more than enough to compute the integral...

Comment: It is strange that the definition in your lecture only concerns holomorphic functions, because it does (and should) make sense for any *continuous* functions.

Comment: Holomorphy isn't needed on the definition. That's a mistake.